# How can I build a list from another list, creating multiple elements for each element in the original list?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to do something like

```
[(x, y, x+y) | (x,y) <- original]
```

But of course, this will return something like:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)]
```

What I want is something like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

I am quite new to Haskell, and unfamiliar with its idioms. How can I accomplish this in Haskell?

Comment: In the future you can use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+%5B%5BInt%5D%5D+-%3E+%5BInt%5D) instead of building functions like in your (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a diatribe on types.  You are drawing the pair `(x,y)` from a list named `original`.  Original must be a list of pairs, `original :: [(a,b)]`, such as `[(1,6), (4,9)]`.  You then construct a tuple for each element, hence your result of a list of tuples.  I am going by the guess that you never wanted any tuples but actually want some number of elements of the list to be combined by your function and concatenate the results into a new list.

You might looking for the `concatMap` function:

```
> :t concatMap
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
> concatMap (\x -> [x,x+1,x+7]) [1,2,3]
[1,2,8,2,3,9,3,4,10]
```

If you actually want to consume two (or more) elements at once then there are a few missing details, such as what to do if you have an odd number of elements and weather or not elements repeat (so you see `[1,2,3]` as two inputs `1,2` and `2,3`).

If elements repeat then this is just a `concatMap` and a `zip`:

```
> let ls = [1,2,3] in concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y,x+y]) (zip ls (drop 1 ls))
[1,2,3,2,3,5]
```

But if you want to see them as [1,2] and [3] then you're best off writing your own function:

```
func [] = []
func [x] = [[x]] -- What do you want with the odd remaining element?
func (x:y:rest) = [x,y,x+y] : func rest

> concat (func [1,2,3])
[1,2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're just making a non-deterministic choice -- just what list comprehensions were made for!

```
[v | (x,y) <- original, v <- [x, y, x+y]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can for example create a list of lists and then use `concat` to flatten it.

```
concat [[x, y, x+y] | (x, y) <- original]
```